# React .NET - Client returns user string with double qoute marks and slash

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identity, react-typescript

I am working with a project and I have 2 endpoints now where an admin can make a user an admin or remove the user as an admin.

This operation is made with the users ID.
But when I enter the button to make/remove an admin, the user ID doesnt return as expected and it gives me a 500 error instead.

This is the Id I get

```
"\"65efe6a5-1384-49f7-8519-8d6789d26baf\""
```

This is the Id I need

```
"65efe6a5-1384-49f7-8519-8d6789d26baf"
```

What might be causing this and how could it be fixed?

backend

```
[HttpPost("assignAdminClaim")]
        //[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = "IsAdmin")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AssignAdminClaim([FromBody] string userId)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("role", "admin"));
            return NoContent();
        }
```

Frontend

```
const assignAdminClaim = async (id: string) => {
        await adminClaim(`${UrlUsers}/assignAdminClaim`, id)
    }

    const adminClaim = async (url: string, id: string) => {
        await axios.post(url, JSON.stringify(id), {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });

        Swal.fire({
            title: "Success",
            text: "Successfully updated",
            icon: "success",
        })
    }
```

All help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Could you share your code snippet that returns this Id?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the question with some code. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to make the backend action receive Guid instead of string?

Comment: or try to send id directly without JSON.stringify(id)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it actually was the JSON.stringify() that caused the issue, I dont know why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As you confirmed that `JSON.stringify()` is the cause, therefore I tried this code in the browser console and figured out that `JSON.stringify()` wraps strings with extra double quotes, check the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Mahmoud Nasr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1769563/mahmoud-nasr)'s comment, I managed to solve the issue. I dont know why, but it appears to be the `JSON.stringify()` that was the cause of the issue. If any one would have more knowledge about why, please let me know!